# gridView height is too tall when using an imageView inside

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I'm having an issue with the height for the cells inside the GridView. Each of my cells will have an imageView inside like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/eventGridView" android:numColumns="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the ImageView for each cell

```
<com.example.scheduling_android.view.RoundedCornerImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:maxHeight="150dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/eventImageView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>
```

I was playing around with different image size for my imageView. What I got was that whenever my image becomes larger (say, 400 x 400px) the height of the cell becomes very tall (around double the size of the width, note that I set the grid to use 2 columns). However, when I save my image as a smaller size (say, 160 x 160px), the gridView came out correctly. The height and the width matches.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

What seems to be the problem? Could it be that the large image is causing gridView to calculate the height of its cell incorrectly? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: how you solved this question? i have met the same problem now...

Answer (score 20):

I think you haven't set adjustViewBounds to true. Can you set as follows?

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here i have user 3 column for in each row and it works fine.
Gallery view set the column width at run time,

```
mPhotoGalleryGridView.setColumnWidth(display.getWidth() / 3);
```

in layout

```
<GridView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/photogallerygridview"      
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:gravity="center">    
</GridView>
```

in adapter: set imageview height and width,

```
imageview.setMaxHeight(150);
        imageview.setMinimumHeight(150);
```

Hope useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrap_content` instead of using `fill_parent`.

Because fill_parent will actually take original height of image and try to fill it in the screen. Even if u use 400x400 image and set 
`layout_width = "160dp"` and `layout_height = "160dp"` , it will work because we are not allowing image to display more than that.

Comment: It would be useful if you provided a reason as to why it is better to use one over the other.

Comment: because fill_parent will actually take original height of image and try to fill it in the screen.. even if u use 400x400 image and set layout_width = "160dp" and layout_height = "160dp" .it will work because we are not allowing image to display more than that

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. The width should be in dips

```
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:maxWidth="150dip"
 android:maxHeight="150dip"
```

Comment: I thought dip is the same as dp?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: I tried this, this doesn't work. GridView cell does not fit image height.